# How can I select Date in Range?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOFGU.png)

How can i select date in Range in android ?
i want a dialog that is shown in this attach image this  Dialog is in fragment .

this is code is Onclick of Date Edittext layout:

```
  dateLI.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {




            MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Pair<Long, Long>> builder =
                    MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker();

            CalendarConstraints.Builder constraintsBuilder = new CalendarConstraints.Builder();
            builder.setCalendarConstraints(constraintsBuilder.build());
            MaterialDatePicker<Pair<Long,Long>> picker = builder.build();
            assert getFragmentManager() != null;
            picker.show(getFragmentManager(), picker.toString());


        }
    });
```

by using this i face this error" r requires a value for the com.example.indicaatabinspector:attr/colorSurface attribute to be set in your app theme. You can either set the attribute in your theme or update your theme to inherit from Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant)."

Comment: Post your code pls

Comment: @GabrieleMariottin please check i attached my code.